# Hovering on parent div not working as desired in Reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs

Front-end code:

```
                return (
                    <div className="card" key={i} >
                        <img src={anime["main_picture"]["medium"]} alt="Anime" className="cardImage"></img>
                        <div className="cardTitle">
                            <p>{anime["title"]}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                );
            })}
```

CSS:

```
.card{
    height: 10vmin;
    flex-direction: row;
    display: flex;
    border-top : 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom : 1px solid #000;
    align-items: center;
}

.card :hover{
    background-color: #E3E3E3;
}
```

when Hovering over the card div, it changes the background color of its child items instead of the whole div. Any ideas as to what's wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a space between your selector and `hover`. It Should be `.card:hover`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know a space in CSS could change the selection

Comment: No problem! Yes, the space selects nodes that are descendent of the first element.